# Fluttet descargar imagnes de internet y Crear una carpeta donde se guarden

Tags: android, api, flutter, imagen

Estoy intentando con flutter descargar una imagen desde internet (de una api que he creado).
pero ademas lo que quiero y no consigo es que me cree una carpaeta nueva donde se guarden esas imagenes,
mi codigo actual para descargar imagnes es este:

```
Response<Uint8List> response = await Dio().get<Uint8List>(
  imageUrl,
  options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes),
);

// Obtiene el directorio de documentos local para guardar la imagen
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String filePath = '${appDocDir.path}/$nameImage.jpg';
// Guarda la imagen localmente
File file = File(filePath);
await file.writeAsBytes(response.data!);

// Guarda la imagen en la galería con una carpeta específica
await ImageGallerySaver.saveImage(
  response.data!,
  name: '$nameImage',
  isReturnImagePathOfIOS: true
);
print('Imagen descargada y guardada en la galería con la carpeta FastGallery');
```

esto me funciona para descargar la imagen pero me lo gauarda en pictures, a mi me gustaria crear una carpeta nueva donde gaurdarlas y decirle que esa es la ubicacion,
Tan bien dejo por aqui mi AndroidManifest, por si tengo algo mal

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="lajara.victor.fastgalery">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application
    android:label="fastgalery"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el plugin [flutter_downloader](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_downloader) para descargar la imagen y guardarla donde tu quieras.
Por ejemplo, puedes crear un boton para descargar la imagen:

```
ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          if (await _checkPermission()) {
            final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
              url: widget.downloadUrl, // URL de la imagen
              savedDir: _localPath, // El directorio donde lo quieres guardar
              showNotification:
                  true, // Muestra el progreso en la barra de notificaciones (for Android)
              openFileFromNotification:
                  true, // Abrir archivo descargado desde la notificacion (for Android)
              saveInPublicStorage: true,
            );
            downloadId = taskId!;
          }
        },
        child: const Text(
          'Downloa File',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        )),
```

El codigo completo:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

  class DownloadFiles extends StatefulWidget {
    final String downloadUrl;

    DownloadFiles({required this.downloadUrl});

    @override
    _DownloadFilesState createState() => _DownloadFilesState();
  }

  class _DownloadFilesState extends State<DownloadFiles> {
    late String downloadId;
    late String _localPath;

    ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _init();
    }

    Future<void> _init() async {
      IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
          _port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
      _port.listen((dynamic data) {
        String id = data[0];
        DownloadTaskStatus status = data[1];
        int progress = data[2];
        print("status: $status");
        print("progress: $progress");
        print("id == downloadId: ${id == downloadId}");
      });
      FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);

      _localPath = '${await _findLocalPath()}/Images';
      final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
      bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
      if (!hasExisted) {
        savedDir.create();
      }
    }

    static void downloadCallback(String id, int status, int progress) {
      print(
          'Background Isolate Callback: task ($id) is in status ($status) and process ($progress)');
      final SendPort send =
          IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port')!;

      send.send([id, status, progress]);
    }


    Future<String> _findLocalPath() async {
      final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
      return directory!.path;
    }


    Future<bool> _checkPermission() async {
      /* Implementa tu logica para comprobar si tienes permisos o no */
      return true;
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------
    @override
    void dispose() {
      super.dispose();
    }

    //-----------------------------------------------------------------

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Column(
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (await _checkPermission()) {
                  final taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
                    url: widget.downloadUrl, // URL de la imagen
                    savedDir: _localPath, // El directorio donde lo quieres guardar
                    showNotification:
                        true, // Muestra el progreso en la barra de notificaciones (for Android)
                    openFileFromNotification:
                        true, // Abrir archivo descargado desde la notificacion (for Android)
                    saveInPublicStorage: true,
                  );
                  downloadId = taskId!;
                }
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Downloa File',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
              )),
        ],
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: muchas gracias, probare a ver que tal, entiendo que la carpeta donde la guarde tiene que existir. no me crearia una nueva carpeta o si?

Comment: si la carpeta no existe, creara la carpeta

Comment: Muchas gracias, cuando retome el proyecto flutter lo probare